# Upside down images issue - need solution

Tags: html, image, orientation

What has happened with code that now SOME right side up images are displaying online upside down even when the code is exactly the same for all images?

I have been a web designer for a million years and I have never had this happen before. I've got it on 2 websites with different code. 1 is just an img tag and the other is an animated gallery. In both cases SOME photos are displaying upside down while others are not, and they are all right side up in real life on the computer.

The upside down thing is happening in Chrome and Safari but not on the iPhone.

Here's code:

Could not possibly get any simpler.

```
<body class="loading">
<div class="page">
<img src="images/Ralphs-sons.jpg" alt="family portrait painting of kids" border="0">
```

Is there a code to lock the orientation so it cannot be flipped by whatever insanity the gurus who break the wheel have done now?

I saw a post about orientation but it didn't make sense for this since I am not doing anything special here and that code was supposed to be to fix a problem in only one web browser, not lock it for all browsers...

Comment: Are these websites that you have created or someone else's?

Comment: I created the websites myself. I just posted an answer to the problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a workaround. I opened the image in Photoshop and saved it from Photoshop so that it is no longer merely recognized by browsers as a photo saved from a camera.